# Why don't we wear tefillin on Yom Tov sheni?

Tags: halacha-theory, tefilin, rambam, yom-tov, derabanan

In *Hilkhoth Tefillin* 4:10, the Rambam states the basic and well-known *halakhah* that "...*shabbathoth wi-yamim tovim enan zeman tefillin*..." (***Translation***: "*Shabbat* and *Yom Tov* are not times for [wearing] *tefillin*"). This is due to the *pasuq* that *tefillin* are meant to be an *oth* ("sign") [cf. *Shemoth* 13:9; *Devarim* 6:8, 11:18, et al] and *Shabbath* and *Yamim Tovim* are already an *oth* by themselves [cf. *Shemoth* 31:17; *Hilkhoth Tefillin* ibid.]

However, there is an interesting statement in *Hilkhoth Evel* 10:10 which says:

הקובר את מתו ביום טוב שני שהוא יום טוב האחרון או ביום טוב שני של עצרת נוהג בו אבילות:  הואיל ויום טוב שני מדבריהם ואבילות יום ראשון מן התורה יידחה עשה של דבריהם מפני עשה של תורה.  אבל אם קבר ביום טוב שני של ראש השנה אינו נוהג בו אבילות ששניהן כיום אחד ארוך הן מהטעם שביארנו בהלכות קידוש החודש

> ***Translation***: "The one who buries his dead on the second day of Yom Tov [*yom tov sheni*], which is the last Yom Tov, or on the second
>   day of the Yom Tov of *Shemini* *Assereth*, conducts himself on it
>   according to all the rules of mourning. Since the second day of Yom
>   Tov [*yom tov sheni*] is rabbinic in nature and the first day of
>   mourning in Biblical in nature, ***the positive commandment of the
>   rabbis is displaced by the positive commandment of the Torah***. But
>   if one buried [his dead] on the second day of Yom Tov [*yom tov
>   sheni*] of *Rosh HaShannah*, he does not conduct himself on it
>   [according to all the rules of] mourning since both days are together
>   considered one long day for the reason that we explained in *Hilkhoth
>   Qidhush HaHodhesh*."

In this *halakhah*, the Rambam seems to communicate a general principle that any *misswath `aseh* (positive commandment) from the Torah displaces a positive directive of rabbinic enactment - in this case, *Yom Tov Sheni*.

So, my question is, if the *gezerah* of *Yom Tov Sheni* does not displace *aveyluth* [halakhic mourning] since it is a *misswath `aseh min ha-torah*, then why would it displace the obligation to wear *tefillin*, since it is also a positive commandment on a Biblical level?

(**NOTE**: I am assuming the position that *tefillin* must be worn on *Holo Shel Mo`edh* and that the Rambam also takes this position in the *Mishneh Torah*.)

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40408&st=&pgnum=273&hilite=

Comment: I don't know why you have to assume that. Most Yom Tov Shenis are not on Chol HaMoed.

Comment: Why don't we blow Shofar on Shabbat? It's a biblical commandment.

Comment: Aruch Hashulchan 31:2 says as follows.

> ואפילו יום טוב שני שהוא מדרבנן – אסור בתפילין, דיש כוח ביד חכמים לעקור
> דבר מן התורה ב"שב ואל תעשה", כמו שופר ולולב כשחל בשבת

Comment: @DoubleAA - Blowing the Shofar on Shabbath is completely different since you have two Biblical commandments and with regard to Shofar, there isn't even a question in this case since the misswah itself is stated in the mesorah as being fulfilled on a weekday but only a "zikharon" when it falls on Shabbath. As to the Holo Shel Mo`edh assumption, I am trying to avoid wasted time. When I asked this question to both rabbinic and lay people I got comments about it about 50% of the time. Kol tuv.

Comment: @GershonGold - Thanks for the reference. I hear that, however, it would seem from this Rambam and from the halakhah that although the hakhamim do have power to uproot a positive commandment from the Torah, they did not do so in this case. Additionally, his comparison to Shofar on Shabbath does not seem analogous. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist The Rambam said that it's a Gezeira, not because of Zichron http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=17&perek=2&halocha=6&hilite=

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Thank you for the reference. I was referring to the opinion of Rav Lewi ben Lahma who said that the two references of "yom terua" and "yom zikharon terua" refer to a weekday and Shabbath, respectively. I am fully aware of Rava's explanation of the Mishnah, brought in the Rambam you referenced, that it was a gezerah lest someone who was not an expert in blowing carry it in a reshuth ha-rabim. However, your reference also proves my point. The Mishnah says that the Shofar was blown even on Shabbath in the Miqdash and later in qualified places with a beth din, because not blowing

Comment: a shofar is a rabbinic shevuth on Shabbath but is not an issur from the Torah itself. Therefore, they admit that without this gezerah to prevent a Torah transgression of hossa'ah, the misswath aseh min ha-torah of teqi`ath shofar should displace the rabbinic shevuth. However, we are not discussing Shofar, but tefillin on Yom Tov Sheni, about which there was never any specific gezerah. Thus, the question remains. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist What downvoting?

Comment: @Maimonist But there is a specific Gezerah: Yom Tov Sheni. What kind of Gezera to observe a day as if it were Yom Tov wouldn't account for the issue of Tefillin?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I hear you. But I guess that is my question. If there is a rabbinic gezerah to observe the second day as if it were YT (and there certainly is) then why wouldn't that gezerah uproot aveyluth also? I think that tefillin is a unique case in this regard, because I really don't think that there is ANY other misswath `aseh min ha-torah that is required on a weekday that becomes displaced on YT sheni. Shema, prayer, the constant misswoth, etc. - they all continue without question on YT sheni, but tefillin seems to be a case in the category of aveyluth. Has anyone ever discussed this? KT.

Comment: @Maimonist I think you should reformulate your question like you just presented it in this comment: We have this Gezera, but why does it treat these two cases differently? ||| Speculation: observing Tefillin fully would be obviously a Zilzul Yom Tov, whereas observing Avelut fully would not be because a full observance of Avelut on Shabbat (I extend here to Yom Tov) involves only Devarim shebeTzin'a which is not Zilzul.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Okay. I reformatted the question in accordance with our discussion and your suggestion. Re: your speculation - I definitely hear you, and I agree that it would definitely be zilzul to wear them in public or to the beth kenesseth on YT sheni, but what about putting them on in private? Is there an essential element of tefillin which is public in nature (i.e. to the point of being me`aqev)? If someone puts them on once in the morning in the privacy of their home, aren't they still yosse yedhei hovatham? Thanks for the help. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist I speculate that Chazal would rather use Shev veAl Taaseh then enact a partial fulfillment of the Mitzva. Perforce the Tefillin would have to be taken off for part of the day (which sounds normal to us now but probably not to Chazal)

Comment: Btw milah shelo bizmana would be another biblical mitzva that is pushed off.

Comment: Consider Beiur Halacha OC 344 sv. Afilu.

Comment: I hesitate to nominate any question for closure, especially one with this much productive discussion attached, but this seems to be an exact duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10444/why-no-tfillin-on-second-day-of-yom-tov?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rambam himself says in [הלכות שביתת יום טוב - פרק ראשון](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02013.html#HtmpReportNum0041_L2)

> כב יוֹם טוֹב שֵׁנִי אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא מִדִּבְרֵי סוֹפְרִים כָּל דָּבָר שֶׁאָסוּר בָּרִאשׁוֹן אָסוּר בַּשֵּׁנִי. וְכָל הַמְחַלֵּל יוֹם טוֹב שֵׁנִי וַאֲפִלּוּ שֶׁל רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה בֵּין בְּדָבָר שֶׁהוּא מִשּׁוּם שְׁבוּת בֵּין בִּמְלָאכָה בֵּין שֶׁיָּצָא חוּץ לַתְּחוּם מַכִּין אוֹתוֹ מַכַּת מַרְדּוּת אוֹ מְנַדִּין אוֹתוֹ אִם לֹא יִהְיֶה מִן הַתַּלְמִידִים. וּכְשֵׁם שֶׁהָרִאשׁוֹן אָסוּר בַּהֶסְפֵּד וְתַעֲנִית וְחַיָּב בְּשִׂמְחָה כָּךְ הַשֵּׁנִי **וְאֵין בֵּינֵיהֶן הֶפְרֵשׁ אֶלָּא לְעִנְיַן מֵת** בִּלְבַד:‏

See the  מגיד משנה there who brings sources, explaining that essentially both days of Yom Tov have the identical status, *with the exception of certain Halachot related to burying and mourning.*

In other words, the question is the other way round: Why is some form of mourning allowed, since the 2 days of Yom Tov are identical?

The answer - based in the sources (ibid) - seems to be that we pasken like Rav Ashi in ביצה [Daf 6a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00884.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2):

> רב אשי אמר אפילו לא אישתהי מ''ט יו''ט שני לגבי מת כחול שויוה רבנן

*Even if there's no risk of the body decaying, the 2nd day of Yom Tov has the status of a weekday as regards burial.*

As I understand it, when they decreed the 2nd day of Yom Tov, they excluded burial and essential mourning - and hence it (and only it) is allowed. The Rambam reinforces this by reminding you it's a Torah obligation to mourn on the first day, and you may not choose to forgo your mourning *in honour of Yom Tov*.

With regards to Tefillin, they did included it in the decree - and therefore one may not wear Tefillin on 2nd day Yom Tov.